# Bootstrap DatePicker format not recogined by ASP.NET MVC validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, date, razor, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker in my ASP.NET MVC application. When I try to post the form, I'm getting error saying `"The field Start Date must be a date."` I'm using `"jquery.validate.js"`to validate in client side. My date picker format, I have customized as `"dd-MM-yyyy"` (Eg: 12-May-2016).

This error is happening only in **IE**, it works fine in **Chrome** browser.

By googling, I tried different ways:

1) Setting up Data Annotations in Model

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

2) Edited `date` function in `jquery.validate.js`

```
date: function (value, element) {           
            return value.match("^\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}$");
        },
```

But nothing seems to be working. Most of the questions are discussing around JQuery datepicker, but mine is bootstrap datepicker.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had this problem. The only work around I found was to pass the dtpicker a string instead of a DateTime and format the string in the model [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis You mean to create my model object as a simple string instead of DateTime field? If yes, will the DisplayFormat attribute support for string object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are  some fixes:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

2.
Go global asax and add:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MMM/yyyy";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    }
```

3. And Finaly try this in  your View

   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {@class = "date-picker form-control"})

Comment: It works for me now. I have changed the format like dd/MM/yyyy instead of dd/MMM/yyyy. Thanks a looot